# How can I know the protocol and develop a application for it?

Tags: skype, instant-messaging

In our country, there is a application called UUCall( an alternative of skype) , and I like it very much, but there is no android application for this. I intend to develop by myself. My question is:

How can I know the communication protocol of it, and develop an application in android ?

Why can someone figure out and develop a application for skype/msn/icq in android ?

Comment: 1. You can ask the developer nicely. 2. People use a) a packet sniffer and/or disassembler, and b) LOTS of coffee or energy drinks, and reverse engineer the protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put a packet sniffer in the way and look for common signatures.
2. Skype's protocol is closed, but as for the [others](http://csclub.uwaterloo.ca/~dtbartle/pidroid/)...

Comment: I don't want to make another skype, I want to know how to figure out the protocol? Do you have any recommended packet sniffer , and how to look for common signatures ?

Comment: I use Wireshark, and signatures come with knowledge and experience.